# Having trouble running friedman test on ordinal data in R

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics

I am attempting to run a friedman test on ordinal data in R and am getting errors. The data can be found here on dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/gh8crh18y1ueriy/seltoutput.xlsx?dl=0.

As a description of the data:

group1: group assignments, 2 levels
time1: time points, 2 levels
loameasure: ordinal data, 5 levels
distmeasure: continuous data
vectemp: participant IDs

After importing the data I run the following to correctly format:

```
  selt$loameasure<-factor(selt$loameasure)  
  selt$distmeasure<-as.numeric(selt$distmeasure)  
  selt$time1<-factor(selt$time1)
```

Then I run:

```
 friedman_test(formula = loameasure ~ time1 | vectemp, data = selt)
```

Then I get the error:
Error in friedman.test.default(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L,  :
not an unreplicated complete block design

I thought that loameasure and time1 had to be factors but I did try them as numeric and I get a similar error:
Error in friedman.test.default(c(3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4,  :
not an unreplicated complete block design

I've been playing around with this for days and haven't been able to figure out what my problem is. I would love some assistance! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you exactly attempt to test. what is group1 (2 levels), what is time1 (2 levels). Would you please define with your words in detail which block should be compared. For example in case your data is normally distributed and you want to perform a ANOVA to compare the means of `loameasure` over a categorical variable...Which one would you choose as it should have at least three levels... Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @TarJae thank you for your response! Group1 is just the two groups that I have. one is a control group and one is an experimental group from a research study. Time1 are the two timepoints at which the data were measured. I would like to find out if loameasure changed from the first to the second timepoint. None of my variables have three measures so does that mean I'm running the wrong test? Thank you again for your response!

Comment: vectemp: participant IDs are all of them unique? That means all in group one are unique and all in group two are unique. Or do some from group1 participate again in group2 two. Which measurment in time1 belongs to time2, or are all timepoints independent. Is there a fixed time between time1 and time2

Comment: yes all participant IDs are unique. there is no time2 variable but within the time1 variable there are two independent timepoints. There is a fixed interval of time between the two timepoints

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can anticipate a Friedman test is not appropriate in your situation. I would suggest to perform a **two-way ANOVA test for unbalanced designs with Type-III sums of square method**.
The assumptions of Normality of residuals and homogenity are given.
I have tried to guide you how to perform the test and the meaning of some steps. It is not complete (lacking of interpretation etc..) But this should be a begin and direction for you.

1. We want to know if loameasure depends on group1 and time1
2. We will perform a two-way anova with two factors
3. Dependent variable: `loameasure`
4. Independent variable: `group1` and `time1`

```
library(readxl)
# load your data
df <- read_excel("C:/Users/coding/Downloads/seltoutput.xlsx", 
                 col_types = c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric")) 

# Prepare data
# group1 to factor 
df$group1 <- factor(df$group1,
                    levels = c(0, 1),
                    labels = c("Group_0", "Group_1"))
# time1 to factor
df$time1 <- factor(df$time1,
                      levels = c(1, 2),
                      labels = c("Time_1", "Time_2"))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Visualize
library("ggpubr")
ggboxplot(df, x = "time1", y = "loameasure", color = "group1",
          palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))

ggline(df, x = "time1", y = "loameasure", color = "group1",
       add = c("mean_se", "dotplot"),
       palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# first decide if balanced or unbalnced design
table(df$group1, df$time1)
# Output

# Time_1 Time_2
# Group_0     20     20
# Group_1     29     29

# Here it is a unbalance design 
# An unbalanced design has unequal numbers of subjects in each group!

## We will perform two-way ANOVA test in R for unbalanced designs !!!!!!!!!!!
# The recommended method are the Type-III sums of squares.
# you need `car` package
library(car)
# Our 2 way anova of unbalanced design (SS Type-III)

df_anova <- aov(loameasure ~ group1 * time1, data = df)
Anova(df_anova, type = "III")

## Output
# Anova Table (Type III tests)
# Response: loameasure
# Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
# (Intercept)  120.050  1 83.9312 1.116e-14 ***
#   group1         0.700  1  0.4891   0.48607    
# time1         62.500  1 43.6960 2.301e-09 ***
#   group1:time1   5.716  1  3.9963   0.04849 *  
#   Residuals    134.452 94                      
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


# Nomrality check ---------------------------------------------------------


# call residuals (difference between each indivdual and their group1/time1 combination mean)
res <- df_anova$residuals

# Histogram of residuals: Residuals should be normally distributed
hist(res,main="Histogram of residuals", xlab = "Residuals")
# # Extract the residuals

# Run Shapiro-Wilk test
shapiro.test(x = res )
# Output
# data:  res
# W = 0.97708, p-value = 0.08434
# P is > 0.05 therefore normality can be assumed.


# Homogenity test ---------------------------------------------------------

# Levene's test for equality of variances (in `car` package)
library(car)
leveneTest(loameasure~ time1 * group1,data=df)

# Output:
# Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
#       Df F value Pr(>F)
# group  3  0.3196 0.8112
#       94  
# P is > 0.05 therefore equal variances can be assumed.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!!!! This actually makes total sense to me. My only question is, this is ordinal data--is it ok for me to be using a parametric test on it?

Comment: It depends on how many points the ordinal variable has. AFAIK fhe use of ANOVA for Likert scale items is at least controversial. You may get help here: <https://stats.stackexchange.com/> If my answer to your first question was helpflul please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. See here: <https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=There%20is%20an%20up%20%26%20down,refers%20to%20downvote%2Fnegative%20voting.>