# Using lme4 to examine differencens in two groups with repeated measurement

Tags: r, difference, lme4

I have a dataset like this (but more complex):

```
     id   Group   time  IS

1    a      0      1     2
2    b      1      1     3
3    a      0      2     5
4    b      1      2     2
5    a      0      3     5
6    b      1      3     8
```

I want to examine:

1. If there is a difference in the depentend variable IS between each time point
2. If there is a difference between the groups in dv IS at each of the three time points and
3. If there is a difference between the groups in how the dv IS differs between the different time points

I figured out that using the lmer package in r for performing mixed models seems to be an adequate approach dealing with this issue.

I started with this function for examine the difference between the timepoints:

```
m1 <- lmer(IS ~ time + (1|id), data = df1, na.action = "na.omit")
```

But I am quite not sure if this is the right way to do this and how I need to adjust the function for the other questions.

Comment: This is a complex question and not easy to solve due to lack of information. It reminds me to this conversation <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549190/having-trouble-running-friedman-test-on-ordinal-data-in-r/66590964#66590964> Therefore in order to get adequate support please provide as much as possible important information to perform this kind of statistics. It is more complex than an one liner from a package. For example: is `IS` ordinal or continuous, In 2. you want to explore each of the 3 time points but in your time column there are 4....

Comment: IS is a metric variable. The fourth time point is a mistake!! There are only three, I'll edit it..